reading from TAP device in linux using C
I am trying to set up a TUN device for reading and writing. I have the following to create the device, set an IP address, and set the state to UP:
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct device {
    char device[IFNAMSIZ];
    char ip_addr[16]; 
} device;

int setip (struct ifreq* ifr, int sock, char ip_addr[]) {

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int stat;

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // s = socket(addr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    stat = inet_pton(addr.sin_family, ip_addr, &addr.sin_addr);
    if (stat == 0)
        printf("invalid ip: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else if (stat == -1)
        printf("invalid family: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    
    if (stat != 1) {
        return -1;
    
    }
    ifr->ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr;

    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFADDR, (void*) ifr) == -1) {
        printf("Unable to set ip address: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int open_tun_dev(device* dev)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;

    if( (fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        printf("Cannot open TUN/TAP dev: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
    if( *dev->device ) {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev->device, IFNAMSIZ);
    }
    

    if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0 ) {
        printf("ERR: Could not ioctl tun: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }
    
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0) {
        printf("Unable to create socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    if(setip(&ifr, sock, dev->ip_addr) < 0) {
        printf("Unable to set ip address: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING;

    if(ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
        printf("Unable to set state to UP: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}      

currently the device shows up in ip address show with the following output:
30: tun0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:5d:06:ac:23:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::309e:cdff:fe47:831f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I am trying to read from the device using its file descriptor with the following driver code:
int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[1];
    char tun_name[IFNAMSIZ] = "tun0";

    device dev;
    
    strcpy(dev.ip_addr, "10.0.0.1");
    strcpy(dev.device, tun_name);
    int tun_fd = open_tun_dev(&dev);
    if(tun_fd < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(1) {
        read(tun_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}

When I run this code, I don't see any output when I ping the IP 10.0.0.1 but the responses reach. When I run the code without the while(1), I get the output 3tun0 (even though the buffer size is one byte) and the program ends. Am I doing something wrong to read from the interface, or am I not supposed to read from it this way? What I would like to be able to do is read the packets destined to this interface.
